Error showing over a show password icon SDK24
For some reason, I need to code on an APK with target SDK 24, so I can't use Material.
I have 3 password fieds to change user password, and the edittexts have a show/hide password icon.
If there is an error, I used setError("error message"); on textfields, and works, but error icon appears over the "eye icon" on show passwords.
If I use padding, show password icon moves to the left, but I don't want to move that icon, I want to move the error icon.
Is there a way to do this?
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/oldpasswd"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:hint="@string/prompt_old_password"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


